# La différence entre « auprès de mon maître » et « près de mon maître »

Tags: usage, prépositions

> J'ai appris mon métier **près de** mon maître.
>
> J'ai appris mon métier **auprès de** mon maître.

---

« **près de** » : Je me demande s'il s'agit plus de la proximité spatiale entre l'apprenti et son maître que des relations proches entre eux. C'est comme s'il suivait physiquement son maître tout le temps ? Il a beau être son apprenti, ça m'étonnerait quand même que ce soit vraiment le cas.

« **auprès de** » : Cela signifie-t-il qu'il suit de près (au sens figuré) ce que son maître fait pour apprendre les ficelles du métier ? Ce qui conviendrait au contexte.

J'ai du mal à comprendre comment utiliser la préposition « auprès de ».

Comment: Je pense que tu as compris l'idée. Autre contexte : "Si tu veux savoir comment t'inscrire sur les listes électorales, tu peux aller te renseigner **auprès de** la mairie". "auprès de X" semble impliquer une discussion avec la personne (donc être proche au sens figuré)...

Comment: @Random Sans aucun doute « Les Poilus de 14-18 » rêvaient des deux sens en chantant *Auprès de ma blonde* mais j’imagine que le sens littéral du mot était à la tête des deux!

Comment: @PapaPoule que veux-tu dire par "était à la tête des deux" ?

Comment: @Random Oups, sorry! In fact I debated hard between “en tete” & “a la tete” before picking the latter & then added “des deux” to avoid what I saw as a possible unintended double meaning. What I meant was: “When singing [the song] I’m sure the WWI soldiers were [day]dreaming about being both close enough to their loves to talk to them (figuratively close) AND close enough to hold them (literally close) but I imagine that **of the two** [senses of the word], the literal sense was **at the top** [of the list]! (I added “des 2 [sens]” to avoid sounding like I meant: “was on their minds”)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Auprès de*, c'est d'abord plus [près](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pr%C3%A8s/63654/difficulte), comme *tout près de* ; « la proximité immédiate ou la durée assez longue », nous dit [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/aupr%C3%A8s_de/6479/difficulte). Au *LBU* (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, §§ 1073 b 5, 1039 a 1), on mentionne que *auprès de* est préféré avec ce qui est **au figuré**, dans le sens de « dans l'esprit, dans l'opinion de » : « Il avait peur que [qqc.] ne déplût à [ qqn.], ce qui pouvait le compromettre, le rabaisser lui-même auprès d'elle. » (Flaubert) et de « en s'adressant à » : « J'insistai auprès de lui pour qu'il allât le voir » (Proust). Parfois on tend vers le complément d'objet indirect : « il s'est plaint auprès de la direction » ([Ac.9](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/aupr%C3%A8s)). Avec un complément de lieu, il ne peut en aucun cas détrôner *à + complément* ; et est presque complètement incompatible avec les adverbes de degré ; ne peut être accompagné de l'infinitif comme dans « La dépense du maréchal a été tout auprès d'être ridicule » (Sévigné, au [Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/aupr%C3%A8s)). Enfin *auprès de* peut être utilisé dans une en comparaison : « Ce service n'est rien auprès de ce qu'il a fait pour moi » (*Robert méthodique*).

Ce bref survol permet de constater certaines nuances dans l'emploi, dont on peut déduire certaines applications un peu *a contrario* pour *près de*. On notera par ailleurs que *près de*, au-delà de la distance proche, peut servir à l'approximation : *Ils étaient près de cinquante*, *Il a dormi près d'une heure* (LBU). On lira aussi avec intérêt les entrées au *TLFi* ([auprès de](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aupr%C3%A8s%20de), [près](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A8s) de).

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer to give because you perfectly got the meaning.

**For both you are right !**